# Why is the volume mixer showing no sound?

Tags: windows-7, audio, speakers

My computer's sound worked perfectly yesterday. I locked the computer, went home for the night, came back today, and now this. NO SETTINGS WERE TOUCHED.

If I open playback devices, the little meter next to the Speakers Realtek High Definition Audio default device shows that there is sound playing.

But the volume mixer shows no sound anywhere, and indeed there is no sound anywhere.

????

Comment: Did you try rebooting yet?

Comment: Sure did. First thing I tried after I realized nothing was muted and the playback device was working fine.

Comment: Correction, did you try a full power cycle reboot?

Comment: Does your system do a windows update automagically?  There were a bunch of packages released late Tuesday night.

Answer (score 1):

Try to look into Realtek High Definition Audio if there isn't sound muted for some channel or type of output. Maybe you will have to enable advanced view in your Realtek High Definition Audio.

Comment: No luck with that. Nothing is muted.

Comment: Did you try to restart your pc?

Comment: @tikend Yes the OP tried rebooting. See this comment: http://superuser.com/questions/552200/why-is-the-volume-mixer-showing-no-sound#comment670971_552200

Comment: Try to show advanced settings in windows sound manager and see if there aren't any channels muted.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a software has updated your drivers to a version which is incompatible with your motherboard. It happened to me, Microsoft Update wanted me to update my LAN adapter, but the new driver was incompatible.

To make sure it's a driver problem, you should open the Device Manager. Then check if there are unrecognized devices or not functioning normally (they have a warning mark).

If that's the case, try this:

Go to your motherboard's manufacturer website and download audio driver.
Install it and reboot.

Or you could also try to update the driver from the Device Manager.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried checking the speakers to make sure they are working? Here is my sound testing process.

1. Get an MP3 player and some headphones.
2. Plug the headphones into the MP3 player and make sure it plays music.
3. Plug the speakers into the MP3 player and listen for sound.
4. Plug the headphones into the computer and listen for sound.

Step 3 makes sure the speakers work, step 4 tests the output device.

Once you check that, you need to make sure the sound isn't going to a different device. If you have multiple playback devices, disable them. Make sure that the default device is set to the correct device. Restart your computer and try again.

If it is still busted, open a few programs that play music. Start a song and take a look at the sound mixer. You should have an column for each program. If you don't, something is wrong with the device/driver.

At this point, you will need to make sure that you computer is capable of playing sound. This means you will need to install a new USB sound device. Generally, you will have to buy a USB headset to test this.

If you can't get sound on a USB device, then we'll need a lot more details and maybe some screenshots to help you more.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this for my computer. I was reading through forums and an answer by a user caught my eye (Installed a SSD from a HDD)

You have to uninstall your speakers sound drivers, take control of HdAudio.sys in Windows/system32/drivers (instructions on how to do this in link), rename it (e.g. backup_HdAudio.sys), and then reboot.

[Original forum and answer by JahMassive](http://www.sevenforums.com/sound-audio/128479-volume-bar-shows-sound-but-no-sound-through-speakers-3.html)

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question. OP did not make any installation/hardware changes.

Comment: I didn't think I did either, but we forget things. Regardless, the symptoms OP's computer had were identical to mine. And I'm not saying mine were 100% caused by a drive change, but they could have been. I'm not sure; I just know the solution worked.